# Add members to Team Foundation Server 2012

Tags: tfs

I just installed TFS on a Windows 7 64-bit and I want to add members to the team. Team members are distributed over our network and I should add them by their IP or computer name. But I don't know how to do that because when I type for example Compter-Test\User in the add member textbox I got the error TF400067 or just:

> Unable to find or windows identity for Compter-Test\User

What should I do?

Comment: So you don't have a AD with all the users, but several workstations with local users?

Comment: Btw: This might be better of on SuperUser than on StackOverflow.

Comment: @JamesBlond Exactly, we dont have an AD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add non AD (local) users to TFS from another machine. You either add an AD and create all the users there or you create for all the users from other machines a local user on your 'server' again (which would be separate form their local users on their workstations). You could then add these users into a workgroup and assign that workgroup to the TFS projects to simplify things.

But at the end you might be better off using VisualStudio online where you don't need to maintain a AD (free for up to 5 users).

Comment: by server you mean the Win7 64-bit which hosts the TFS? If I do so how should the client connect to the server? They use VS on their workstation. @JamesBlond

Comment: Yes, by server I mean your windows 7 machine. What version of TFS and Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: VS 2012 and TFS 2012. But other clients may use other versions of VS. @JamesBlond

Comment: No, It is Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012.

Comment: You should be able to define a username and password as described in the following MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181475.aspx

Comment: But the questions remain: Why not set up an AD (sounds like you could use one) or use Visual Studio online?

Comment: Ok, I'll check that. I would set up an AD If I was allowed. I'm not the network admin.

Comment: This tutorial is for loging into the server, as mentioned in it too, I should first define new members (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj920206.aspx). which I couldn't.

Comment: As mentioned above. Create local users on your server (Win7 with TFS) for all the users you want to have access. You can then select these users in the TFS administration.

Comment: I second James... Use VSO. Go to http://tfs.visualstudio.com and setup a free TFS server that you can do everything with